# OSX Keyboard Shortcuts in Dialogs?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

On Windows, every dialog box includes underlined letters that you can activate using the Alt key.  I use these "Alt" keyboard shortcuts all the time; I'm missing them as I'm trying to switch to OSX.

On OSX, all I can find is Tab navigation, which requires you to press Tab seven or eight times to get anywhere in most dialog boxes.  (And even that is hidden by default: you have to enable "Full keyboard access" in the "Keyboard & Mouse" control panel to be able to Tab between buttons.)

Is there some way I can get something like the Windows Alt accelerators for OSX dialogs?  I'm willing to write Automator code, download/purchase software, etc.

Specifically, I'm imagining maybe something where you do some shortcut command and then start typing the name of the button, and hit Enter to push the button...?

Comment: Nearly identical question: http://superuser.com/questions/29660/accessing-menus-in-mac-os-x-via-keyboard

Comment: Hopefully I can give the bounty to a better answer than mine. I'll delete this once it's over.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In OSX there's no such thing as the "_" for dialogs like in Windows. However, you have:

<kbd>esc</kbd> → defaults to `no/cancel`

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd> → `don't save` (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> before OS X Lion)

<kbd>enter</kbd> → `save/OK`

<kbd>spacebar</kbd> → `click selected button` (use <kbd>tab</kbd> to move).

A quick [Google search for "osx keyboard shortcuts"](https://www.google.com/search?q=osx+keyboard+shortcuts) will teach you way more than you can memorize in one day, but you should; there are dozens and some are very valuable.

You can always add more/change some existing ones by going to `System Preferences -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Keyboard Shortcuts`, exactly where you activated "all controls".

But as far as I know, there's no "underscore" thing in OSX.

Comment: Also note the "keyboard navigation" section in the "keyboard shortcuts" tab of the Keyboard & Mouse preference pane, specifically the item "move focus to the menu bar". Not exactly what you wanted, but this allows you to navigate the menu bar and its menus using only the keyboard.

Comment: tab seems to do nothing what is going on?

Comment: This answer was true for older versions of macOS, but I'm now on macOS Ventura and dialog windows allow for almost zero shortcuts. The only exception is the Esc key, which still works to remove the dialog from the screen, but you can't use any key to select any button, no Cmd+Del, no Tab, no Space, no Enter, nothing!! You HAVE to use the mouse to interact with dialog windows now. That's horrible usability. Why the regression just for a slight cosmetic change to the dialogs?

Comment: Well, I found the only shortcut that works now, which is Cmd+Initial of the button you want to press. So the mouse is not completely required for dialogs, but the rest of shortcuts were removed for no good reason.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Martín's essential list of shortcuts (which work almost everywhere), you should know that in a File Open or File Save dialog you can press <kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>~</kbd> to jump straight to a popup sheet that will let you type in a folder path. This is great for if you are a super fast typist, or if you want to go to a hidden folder like `~/.ssh`.

That field even does Tab Completion, sort-of—the catch is if there are zero matches, or more than one match, when you press `Tab`, instead of doing any kind of completion Tab will just jump you out of the text field.

Also, when you're in the midst of quitting an app or closing a window, and there's a dialog saying "Cancel"/"Save"/"Don't Save" you can press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to choose "Don't Save." Obviously <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd> will operate the other two buttons, but I use this one all the time when I'm closing something I don't want to save.

Comment: Fantastic! Had no idea there is such an intuitive shortcut. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, in newer versions of macOS (at least in macOS Ventura) the Return/Enter key doesn't work. The only way to click on "Save" is with the mouse now.

Comment: Well, I found the one shortcut that works now, which is Cmd+Initial of the button, so Cmd+S would work for Save.

Answer (score 9):

A nice feature that almost replicates the Windows Alt accelerators in an OS X dialog box is to use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>first_letter</kbd>.

As noted by Louis, using only <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>first_letter</kbd> works in some dialogs. For example, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will choose `Don't Save` on exiting a file. (This is the same funcionality as first using <kbd>⇥</kbd> to highlight `Don't Save` and then selecting it by clicking  <kbd>space</kbd>, which works if `System preferences --> Keyboard --> Keyboard Shortcuts --> Full Keyboard Access:...` is set to `All controls` as described in previous posts).

However, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>first_letter</kbd> is not universal. For example, in a `Save As` dialog, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> fails to select `New Folder`.

But <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> does the trick.

I discovered this feature only recently, so I'm not sure if it is as universal as Windows Alt (which I'm using extensively). But by playing around I seem to be able to select most dialog items that I need. For example, I could use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to navigate in the dialog that opens in Microsoft Excel (for Mac) when I do `Paste Special`, and choose `Text` from a drop-down menu. So it selects not only buttons, but list items as well.

**UPDATE:** One limitation, however, compared with Windows Alt, seems to be that it's not possible to press the first-letter key multiple times to move between different objects that share the same first letter. In lists, this can be overcome to some extent by combining the shortcut with the arrow keys <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd>.

By the way, OS X has the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> for accessing the menu bar, but this is particularly inconvenient since it involves pressing <kbd>fn</kbd> to activate the <kbd>F2</kbd> functionality. (What's more, others [have reported problems](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12723/control-f2-move-focus-to-menu-bar-only-works-occasionally) with the default shortcut.)

The default shortcut can be re-defined in `System preferences --> Keyboard --> Keyboard Shortcuts --> Keyboard & Text Input --> Move focus to the menu bar` (it must involve two keys; I'm using <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>, which feels familiar from Windows). Once the menu bar apple `` is highlighted, it is possible to accesss individual menu items by pressing a sequence of the relevant first letters. For example, in Firefox, I can go to `File --> Page Setup...` with this combo:

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>↩</kbd>

And contrary to dialogs, this functionality does indeed support pressing multiple times to navigate between list items, so that I can access `File --> Print` like so:

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>↩</kbd> (equivalent to  <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>).

It is actually not even necessary to press the relevant *first* letter, it's enough to press *any* letter to highlight the closest list item in alphabetical order (if no result is found, the search continues backwards in reverse order). For example, I can access `Edit --> Undo` (equivalent to  <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>) like this:

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd> (rather than the intuitive <kbd>U</kbd>).

Answer (score 4):

**Ctrl-F7**  allows you to toggle the ability press tab to select different buttons in any OS X dialogue window. This has been around [since at least 2002](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021204061718968).

The setting is under System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard > "Change the way Tab moves focus" and defaults to Ctrl-F7.

Comment: With this information, OSX suddenly becomes usable!

Comment: I cannot believe that I found out this after using mac for about 10 years.

Answer (score 4):

I found this thread because I was searching for an answer for the same issue. I set "Full keyboard access", but this still apparently does not work in all circumstances.

In my example: when attempting to save over a file with the Replace File dialog, there are 2 buttons on screen: **cancel** and **replace**. The **cancel** button is always *filled* with a blue color, but the blue *outline* is displayed around the **return** button by default. It is possible to hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to move the blue outline, but hitting <kbd>return</kbd> will always count as if you clicked **cancel** (the button filled in with blue). That sounds confusing, because it *is* confusing!

I was fumbling around, and just discovered a new keyboard shortcut:

---

In the **Replace File** dialog:

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> : selects the "replace" button.

---

(Adobe seems to be aware of this issue: when you select "Save for Web", a custom save dialog will be used, where it IS possible to simply hit <kbd>return</kbd> to use the "Replace" action (no need for <kbd>tab</kbd>).

Comment: I've been wishing for a shortcut for the "Replace File" button in the "Save As" dialog for ages, and you've found it - well done, very useful!

Comment: In the kind of circumstance you've described a blue fill is static and triggered by <kbd>enter ⏎</kbd>. A blue outline is triggered by <kbd>space ⎵</kbd>, and you can iterate what's selected with <kbd>tab ⇥</kbd>.

Note that in some circumstances, especially in recent versions of macOS, there is not outlined optioned. In these cases, you'll need to use a different method to trigger a non-default action.

Answer (score 2):

The following is [from User588](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7263/how-can-i-activate-buttons-with-just-the-keyboard/7269#7269) on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). It will allow you to <kbd>tab</kbd> to a button, where you can hit <kbd>return</kbd>. It also points out some irregularities.

#### Enable Keyboard Control of the UI

```
System Prefs > Keyboard
```

Then select "All Controls" button at the bottom, rather than just "Text boxes and lists only"

[image]

#### Keyboard Shortcuts

- <kbd>⇥</kbd> (TAB) will move between buttons.
- <kbd>esc</kbd> (ESC) is **cancel**.
- <kbd>space</kbd> (SPACE) selects the **active** button (blue, outline).
- <kbd>↩</kbd> (RETURN) is **OK** or the **default** button (blue, pulsing, filled).
- For some dialog boxes, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>first_letter</kbd> will select the button with a certain first letter in the text (as pointed out by @Griffo).

Answer (score 0):

With soome dialogs like iTunes Song Info dialog, the shortcut to the OK button is <kbd>fn</kbd> → <kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible in OS/X. And a key reason I do not prefer Macs.

The OP points out a critical failing in OS/X: the ability to rapidly - and with only the keyboard - select *any* entries (not just "OK / cancel", etc) in a dialog box. None of the suggestions above can do that.

A common example is:  within a  Find/Replace dialog I want to change from Case Sensitive to Case Insensitive.   In Linux (and in windows) I can achieve that using only keystrokes.  This is not possible in MAC: you have to use the mouse or fumble around with tabbing multiple times.

*Update* : Nine years later and this is still a solid answer - naysayers notwithstanding.  I have only used a Macbook during this entire time and have even worked at Apple contributing to `iTunes` and to their data ingestion infrastructure. Lack of support for mnemonics is the biggest failing of this otherwise v good operating system.

Comment: If you turn on Full Keyboard Access, then this is possible in most apps. Certainly ones designed properly. I've found the opposite of what you're saying. In Windows, shortcuts for things like "Select All" (Command-A) don't exist in every text field, the way they do on a Mac. (Not sure about Linux GUI environments, so I can't comment, but I don't remember them being super consistent.

Comment: It is *not* possible in Find/Replace in most apps.

Comment: I don't know what apps you're using, but it works fine for me in TextMate: http://imgur.com/a/NWgze (note the halo there that I've tabbed into). Most stock apps I tested like Safari are using a little bar that comes down, which also allows tabbing to all the controls (also pictured). Nobody would dispute that apps vary, but any app can break the UI rules on any platform. It appears that you may not have enabled Full Keyboard Access.

Comment: oh i know all about full keyboard access.  Try Sublime text. Or intellij

Comment: FWIW, @javadba neither the Java toolkit used for Intellij nor Sublime use standard AppKit controls. Sublime Search and Replace is a custom widget at the bottom, and Intellij (and Android Studio) more often than not have problems with focus and windows that outlive lifecycle (dialogs floating even though you switched apps…) In part this is macOS’s fault (I agree its keyboard support is subpar in many areas), but from there to being a _key reason not to use it_ is a little bit too much for me. There are many bad things about macOS (especially lately), but that one is not my top concern.

Comment: Well then mnemonics are not as important to you as they are to me: that does not change this answer wrt lack of them being huge failing.  I did not use Macos for a few years *just* because of this.