# What is the keyboard shortcut to access Microsoft Word's menu on OSX?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

When using Microsoft Word on a PC, I can hold the alt key, and it will let me access any item on the program menu. It will also show the keyboard shortcut for every item on that menu, as shown below.

[image: Word for Windows]

However I cannot find the equivalent shortcut on the Mac version of Microsoft Word. How do I access the microsoft word menu through the keyboard when using OSX?

Edit: To clarify, I seek to access this menu:

[image: correct menu]

not this menu, which can be accessed through <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

[image: incorrect menut]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Menus in Mac OS X via Keyboard](http://superuser.com/questions/29660/accessing-menus-in-mac-os-x-via-keyboard) Might be old, but it's still valid.

Comment: @Tetsujin Added clarification on why my question is different. Namely, that I wish to access a different menu than the one specified in the potential duplicate.

Comment: Ah, OK... then not a dupe [I retracted my vote] - that looks like one of Microsoft's "go it alone & ignore all aspects of the Mac Toolbox Guidelines" menus. Wish you luck, but I've no idea, sorry, never used recent versions of Office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Microsoft Word are you using?

According to [this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/navigating-the-ribbon-with-keyboard-shortcuts-in/908e9e5b-0796-475e-aa0c-3891eab4a436), that functionality is not supported in Word 2011 for OS X.

Edit: Additionally [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237327/how-do-i-navigate-the-ribbon-in-office-for-mac-2016-with-the-keyboard?newreg=9e4c9cd49ad5412d9cbff2ec3c54d1cd) on the apple Stack Exchange says that alt-shortcuts have not been implemented in the 2016 version either.

Comment: MS word 2016, version 15.23.2

Comment: Apparently it has not been implemented in the 2016 version either. Edited that into the answer.

Comment: Apparently those shortcuts, or more specifically icons that display shortcuts, are not exactly a feature of Word. They are a part of Windows. OS X doesn't have some equivalent. It is explained in the answer in first link.